# How to send Information from one Device to another Device in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, button

I want to send a Button Value to another Device. So if I click the Button in the first Device, it should be disabled to click in the second Device. How to implement this? Thanks for your Answers.

Answer (score 0):

Use firestore, add on value added listener and implement your algorithm, to can use Boolean , true or false to check. If true then a second phone button can be on and so on.
,